# c# have the parent class method using a subclass variable

Tags: c#, oop, inheritance

I have been facing a challenge, questioning my faith in OOP. Kindly let me know how if this is possible:

I have a parent class with a Static List (to keep track of all objects created, mainly for UI DataGrid reasons) and a Method referring to that List. Something like that

```
abstract class Animal
{
    public static List<Animal> objList;
    public String Name;

    public Animal(String Name)
    {
        this.Name = Name;
        objList.Add(this);
    }

    public virtual void delete(int i)
    {
        objList.RemoveAt(i);
    }
```

now I have a child class with also a static list (same name same purpose just different class) but in order to have the method referring to the child.list I have to rewrite the method. like that

```
class Cat : Animal
{
    public static List<Cat> objList;

    public Cat(String Name) : base(Name)
    {

    }

    //whould it be possible to ommit this method?
    public override void delete(int i)
    {
        objList.RemoveAt(i);
    }
}
```

This cannot be the best way. If I would have 5 children they would all have the same part of code copy pasted.
There must be a way that the parent class "delete" method, if called from a child object, it deletes from the child list, not from the parent list.

Comment: These problems are **much** easier to visualise if you use real class names rather than Child or Parent.

Comment: I'm not 100% sure what you are trying to accomplish, but you can implement all of the desired functionality in the Parent class. For instance, you can filter the Parent List to give you all instances that inherit from Child.

Comment: Are you not getting warnings about the child class hiding the `objList` member without using `new`?

Comment: Why is it a virtual method? If it's the same code for every child, why override?

Comment: Also, you should make the delete function static.

Comment: I am indeed getting warnings.
I also would prefer not to use a virtual method ... (perhaps the static one would make sense)
I want to have a list of objects for each child class (cat, dog, fish) and manipulate these lists with a method in animal (delete).
So when Cat.delete() is called it delets from the static List of cats

Comment: I think a better way to go about your problem would be to create a container object whose responsibility is to add, delete and iterate through your Cats or Animals.

Comment: Have you considered `abstract class Animal<T>
    {
        public static List<Animal<T>> objList;`? Then `class Cat : Animal<Cat>`? I suspect then that you won't need **any** overrides in `Cat`.

Comment: You have, you say, five such classes, and each one has a one-line method, so what you're stressing about here is five lines of code. Stress about something that matters!

Comment: Why do you need two lists?  One in base and one in inherited?

Comment: @mjwills I am not yet very comfortable with creating generic classes. But you are right that my main issue is actually the passing around of types. What i am trying to learn is how to write efficient code. "Eric Lippert" is right that basically it is just copy pasting code, but it just does not feel right to do so. I thought that when I inherit a method it is the same as if I would have it in the child class, and that it would point to the properties of the child class if they were "overriden" like objList. It seems I have to study those Generics :)

Answer (score 0):

Static properties and methods don't lend themselves to being overridden in an OOP manner, though they can be shadowed.

```
public class Parent : IDisposable
{
    private static List<Parent> objList = new List<Parent>();
    private static IReadOnlyList<Parent> readOnlyList = new ReadOnlyCollection<Parent>(objList);
    public static IEnumerable<Parent> Instances { get { return readOnlyList; } }

    private bool _isDisposed = false;
    public bool IsDisposed {  get { return _isDisposed;  } }

    public Parent()
    {
        objList.Add(this);
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        OnDispose(true);
        GC.SuppressFinalize(this);
    }

    protected virtual void OnDispose(bool disposing)
    {
        if(disposing) { objList.Remove(this); }
        _isDisposed = true;
    }
}

public class Child : Parent
{
    private static IEnumerable<Child> _instances = Parent.Instances.OfType<Child>();
    public new static IEnumerable<Child> Instances { get { return _instances; }}

    public Child() : base()
    {

    }
}
```

Now if you want to remove the ith item from the list, just use use **Parent.Instances(i).Dispose();**

You can also remove the ith Child instance by doing **Child.Instances(i).Dispose()**

**Edit:** Finalizer removed from Parent as suggested in the comments below.

**Edit2:** Simplified the LINQ expression in the Child class to use .OfType() as suggested in the comments.

Comment: I did not downvote, but I object to using the disposable pattern "off label" in this manner, though doing so is common.  We reasonably expect that the disposable pattern is used to *politely clean up unmanaged resources*, but there is no unmanaged resource being managed here.

Comment: @EricLippert The IDisposable pattern can legitimately be used to cleanup managed resources as well (hence the OnDispose function takes a boolean to differentiate the context), though the primary intention of the interface was for handling umanaged resources. But if you have a better alternative that properly cleans up the managed resources without using IDisposable here, and without creating a duplicate of the IDisposable interface, then I'd like to see it.

Comment: I think I may have been insufficiently clear in my objection; mjwills points in the right direction. The problem is not just whether the resource is managed or not. **The fundamental problem is that disposing a resource should be a matter of politeness and performance**, and not *program semantics*. You ask for an alternative; `try-finally` is the appropriate alternative when the "disposal" logic has semantic importance. However, I am aware that I am deeply in the minority here; people use `using` and `IDisposable` for all kinds of things it was not designed for.

Comment: @RyanPierceWilliams An article I find useful on finalizers - https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/cbrumme/2004/02/20/finalization/ (under 'Reachability').

Answer (score -1):

The collection does not belong in the base class, and certainly, it does not belong in any derived classes.

Unfortunately, you do not show how your `List<Animal>` is used so it is difficult to show a meaningful answer without inferring behavior you might not desire.

But if you insist, you need to have **one collection only** to hold all the animals and to declare a static property that filters the original collection according to the type in each subclass.

```
public abstract class Animal
{
    // this is the _only_ field that should contain
    // a list of all the animals.
    protected static readonly List<Animal> animals = new List<Animal>();

    // Expose a read-only wrapper as public
    public static IReadOnlyList<Animal> AllAnimals => animals.AsReadOnly();

    protected Animal(string color)
    {
        animals.Add(this);
        this.Color = color;
    }
    public string Color { get; }

    public void RemoveMe()
    {
        int index = animals.IndexOf(this);
        if (index >= 0)
        {
            animals.RemoveAt(index);
        }
    }
}    

public class Cat : Animal
{
    public static IReadOnlyList<Cat> AllCats => animals.OfType<Cat>().ToList().AsReadOnly();
    public Cat(string name, string color) : base(color)
    {
        this.Name = name;
    }
    public string Name { get; }
}

public class Fish : Animal
{
    public static IReadOnlyList<Fish> AllFish => animals.OfType<Fish>().ToList().AsReadOnly();
    public Fish(string color) : base(color)
    {
    }
}

static class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var cat1 = new Cat("Whiskers", "Tabby");
        var fish1 = new Fish("Striped");
        var cat2 = new Cat("Snoflake", "White");
        var cat3 = new Cat("Midnight", "Black");

        cat2.RemoveMe();

        // list all remaining cats below
        foreach (var cat in Cat.AllCats)
        {
            Debug.WriteLine($"{cat.Name} is a {cat.Color} cat.");
        }
        // Result in Output:
        //Whiskers is a Tabby cat.
        //Midnight is a Black cat.

    }
}
```

Comment: The problem with this approach is that the animals field, which you describe as holding a reference of all animals, won't contain all animals once someone invokes RemoveMe(). Someone could still hold a reference to an instance that was removed. If the intent is to have a list that is distinct from all instances, that list shouldn't be part of the Animal class hierarchy.

Comment: @RyanPierceWilliams - yes, but it is understood that `animals` will be the master list, and if you want the most up-to-date info, you go there to get it. A reference in a local variable is a short-lived object that will disappear as soon as it goes out of scope (like a dialog box closing).

Comment: You can't assume that no one else has a reference to one of those animals that you requested be removed. It might work in your simple demo, but not in the real world.

Comment: @RyanPierceWilliams - This "problem" is part of the design of C#. Nobody can stop you from holding a reference from an item in the collection. And I don't see how any code can change that.

Comment: There are ways to address this fact, and you need to do so in this scenario. I addressed this in my answer by having the classes implement IDisposable with an IsDisposed property. Thus the list becomes a list of undisposed instances. If other references are passed around the code, those references will also become disposed of. There are other possible alternatives, such as by using WeakReferences.

Comment: @RyanPierceWilliams - I think you are putting very strict design requirements for a question that is not well defined at all. Without know the intent of the _OP_ for the list of animals and why this list needs to be a static field you are overreaching I think. Also, the _OP_ never mentioned he needs the items to be disposable. If that is the case, then it is an easy fix to implement the standard `IDisposable()` pattern here.

Comment: I think the problem is clear enough that the only two answers are nearly identical. The OP clearly wants to maintain a list of instances of his classes in the Parent, and then be able to filter by derived type. The problem with this answer is that it doesn't properly maintain the list of instances. Using the IDisposable pattern is one way to meet his needs while properly managing the instances.